# how to print double using rounded number of decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, double, razor-2

C# 4.0 ASP.NET MVC4 application contains Out method called from Razor views.
It receives rounded double as parameter.

```
protected static string Out( double roundedValue ) {
  return roundedValue.ToString();  
}
```

it should return number of decimal places into which value is rounded to show in view. E.q

```
Out( Math.Round(1.2f, 2));
```

should return  1.20

and

```
Out( Math.Round(1.2f,3 ));
```

should return 1.200

Actually first call returns 1.2 . It looks like trailing zeroes are removed by ToString().
How to force Out method to return number of decimal places specified in Round call,

e.q

```
Out( Math.Round(1.2f, 2));
```

should return  1.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that `float` and `double` *don't* retain trailing zeroes. You have two options:

- Specify the format to include the number of decimal places you're interested in
- Use `decimal`, which *does* retain trailing zeroes

It's not clear from your question which option is the most appropriate. If this is a currency value (e.g. a price) then you should definitely be using `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken by the concept of rounding a number and displaying a value. `Math.Round()` only rounds to the number of decimal places that you are using. It has no effect on the number of decimal places the `.Tostring()` function puts at the end. You will need to use the following formatting to output the way you want:

```
    float number = 1.23f;
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("0.000")); //1.230
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("0.00"));  //1.23
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("0.0"));   //1.2
```

Please see the [MSDN page on .ToString() Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to see more. :)